# Showing that $\int_0^1 x^{\lambda} [ \: \phi(x) - \phi(0)\: ] dx$ is convergent for $\lambda > -2$

Tags: integration, asymptotics, distribution-theory

Id' appreciate help understanding why the integral

$$
\int_0^1 x^{\lambda} [ \: \phi(x) - \phi(0)\: ] dx
$$

is convergent provided $\lambda > -2$, where $\phi \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$.

To provide some context: this integral arises in the regularization of the (divergent) integral of $x^{\lambda}_+$ ; i.e.

$$
\langle x^{\lambda}_+ , \phi \rangle = \int_0^\infty x^{\lambda} \phi \: dx
$$

By analytic continuation, this integral can be expressed as

$$
\int_0^1 x^{\lambda} [ \: \phi(x) - \phi(0)\: ] dx + \int_1^\infty x^{\lambda} \: \phi(x) \: dx \: + \: \frac{\phi(0)}{\lambda + 1}
$$

The following texts all state that the first integral is convergent provided $\lambda > -2$, but its not obvious to me how it does.

1. Generalized Functions, Volume 1 by Gelfand and Shilov (1964) -- page 47 & 48
2. Theory of Distributions by M. A. Al-Gwaiz (1992), page 64
3. Asymptotic approximation of integrals by R. Wong (2001) -- page 258

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have for $0\leq x\leq 1$:
\begin{align*}
\left|x^{\lambda}(\phi(x)-\phi(0))\right|&=\left|x^{\lambda}\int_0^x\phi'(t)dt\right|\\
&=\left|x^{\lambda}\left(x\phi'(x)-\int_0^xt\phi''(t)dt\right)\right|\\
&\leq x^{\lambda+1}|\phi'(x)|+x^{\lambda}\int_0^xt\phi''(t)dt\\
&\leq x^{\lambda+1}\sup_{t\in\mathbb R}|\phi''(t)|+x^{\lambda+1}\int_0^x|\phi''(t)|dt \\
&\leq x^{\lambda+1}\sup_{t\in\mathbb R}|\phi''(t)|+x^{\lambda+2}\sup_{t\in\mathbb R}|\phi'(t)| \\
&\leq x^{\lambda+1}\left(\sup_{t\in\mathbb R}|\phi''(t)|+\sup_{t\in\mathbb R}|\phi'(t)|\right)
\end{align*}
Since $\lambda+1>-1$ and $\phi'$ and $\phi''$ are bounded, the integral is (absolutely) convergent.

Comment: Thanks Davide. I'm unable to justify the change of the limit and variable of the second integral from $\int_0^x$ to $\int_0^1$. Is this change really necessary?

Comment: I don't know, but in any case the bound $\left|x^{\lambda}\int_0^xt\phi''(t)dt\right|\leq x^{\lambda+1}\sup_{t\in\mathbb R}|\phi''(t)|$ is not enough.

Comment: Sorry, in fact this bound is enough, since $x^{\lambda+1}$ is integrable.

Comment: Just to clarify. Are you saying that the first two steps (up till the integration by parts) are sufficient, and that the third and fourth steps (integration by substitution) is not required?

Comment: Yes, I will edit it.

Comment: On second thoughts I'm leaning toward your former remark, i.e. $\int_0^x t \phi^{\prime\prime} dt \le x \int_0^x \phi^{\prime\prime} dt$. Is this correct?

Comment: In fact, we have $|x^{\lambda}\int_0^xt\phi''(t)dt|\leq x^{\lambda+2}\sup_{t\in\mathbb R}|\phi''(t)|\leq x^{\lambda+1}\sup_{t\in\mathbb R}|\phi''(t)|$, so in fact we get the inequality I gave.

Comment: I'm afraid to say that I don't know where you get sup$_{t \in \mathbb{R}} |\phi^{\prime\prime}(t)|$ from (I'm teaching myself mathematics). Also, is my previous remark correct?

Comment: What you said is correct if $\phi''$ is non-negative. I will give more details in the answer.

Comment: BTW, I've just posted a follow up to this question at: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100979/simplifying-the-generalized-function-x-lambda-in-the-strip-n-1-mbo