# Simplifying the generalized function $x^{\lambda}_+$ in the strip $-n - 1 < \mbox{Re}\lambda < -n$

Tags: integration, asymptotics, distribution-theory

**Note**: this post is a follow up to an [earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95792/showing-that-int-01-x-lambda-phix-phi0-dx-is-convergent).

The (divergent) integral of $x^{\lambda}_+$ can be analytically continued into the region Re $\lambda > -n - 1$, $\lambda \ne -1, -2 , \ldots , -n$ by the expression

$$
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty x^{\lambda} \phi \: dx &= \int_0^1 x^{\lambda} \left[ \phi(x) - \phi(0) - x \phi^\prime(0) - \cdots -\frac{x^{n - 1}}{(n - 1)!}\phi^{(n - 1)}(0) \right] dx \\\
&+ \int_1^\infty x^\lambda \phi(x) dx + \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{\phi^{(k - 1)}(0)}{(k - 1)! (\lambda + k)}.
\end{align*}
$$

This is achieved by a repeatedly applying the first $n$ terms of the Taylor expansion of $\phi$ at $x = 0$, by a generalization of the method discussed in my [earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95792/showing-that-int-01-x-lambda-phix-phi0-dx-is-convergent).

According to the texts that I'm studying, in any strip of the form $-n - 1 < \mbox{Re}\lambda < -n$ the above equation can be written in the simple form:

$$
\langle x^{\lambda}_+ , \phi \rangle = \int_0^\infty x^{\lambda} \left[ \phi(x) - \phi(0) - x \phi^\prime(0) - \cdots -\frac{x^{n - 1}}{(n - 1)!}\phi^{(n - 1)}(0) \right] dx.
$$

It seems like a trivial step, as none of the texts that I'm studying bother to explain it; However, I've spent exactly one week trying to figure out this step but I'm nowhere near doing so.

**Reference texts**:

1. *Generalized Functions*, Volume 1 by Gelfand and Shilov (1964) -- page 47 & 48
2. *Asymptotic approximation of integrals* by R. Wong (2001) -- page 258
3. *Generalized Functions*: theory and technique by Ram P. kanwal (1998) -- page 86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because
$$
\int_1^{\infty} x^{\lambda}dx \; = \; -\frac{1}{\lambda + k}
$$
It follows that
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^{n} \frac{\phi^{(k - 1)}(0)}{(k - 1)! (\lambda + k)} \; = \; \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \frac{-\phi^{(k - 1)}(0)}{(k - 1)!} \int_1^{\infty} x^{\lambda + k - 1} dx
$$
Therefore
$$
\int_1^\infty x^\lambda \phi(x) dx \; + \; \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{\phi^{(k - 1)}(0)}{(k - 1)! (\lambda + k)} \; = \; \int_1^{\infty} x^{\lambda} \left[ \phi(x) - \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \frac{\phi^{(k - 1)}(0) \, x^{k - 1}}{(k - 1)!} \right] dx
$$
Adding this integral to the integral from $0$ to $1$ completes the proof.

Comment: Of course there's still the small issue of the condition $-n - 1 < \mbox{Re}\lambda < -n$

Answer (score 1):

We have 
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{+\infty}x^{\lambda}\left(\phi(x)-\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{\phi^{(j)}(0)}{j!}x^j\right)dx
&=\int_0^1x^{\lambda}\left(\phi(x)-\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{\phi^{(j)}(0)}{j!}x^j\right)dx \\
&+\int_1^{+\infty}x^{\lambda}\phi(x)dx-\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{\phi^{(j)}(0)}{j!}\int_1^{+\infty}x^{\lambda+j}dx\\
&=\int_0^1x^{\lambda}\left(\phi(x)-\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{\phi^{(j)}(0)}{j!}x^j\right)dx\\
&+\int_1^{+\infty}x^{\lambda}\phi(x)dx-\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{\phi^{(j)}(0)}{j!}\frac 1{\lambda+j+1}\\
&=\int_0^1x^{\lambda}\left(\phi(x)-\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{\phi^{(j)}(0)}{j!}x^j\right)dx\\
&+\int_1^{+\infty}x^{\lambda}\phi(x)dx-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\phi^{(k-1)}(0)}{(k-1)!}\frac 1{\lambda+k}.\\
\end{align*}
The integrals $\int_1^{+\infty}x^{\lambda+j}dx$ are absolutely convergent since $|x^{\lambda+j}|=x^{\operatorname{Re}\lambda+j}\leq x^{\operatorname{Re}\lambda+n-1}$ and the integral $\int_1^{+\infty}x^{\operatorname{Re}\lambda+n-1}dx$ is convergent since $\operatorname{Re}\lambda+n-1<-1$.

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify. Does this actually show that the first equation reduces to the second in the strip i.e. when $-n - 1 < Re \lambda < -n$?

Comment: Yes, the fact that the integrals $\int_1^{+\infty}x^{\lambda+j}$ are convergent helps us to simplify the first formula.

Comment: I don't understand step 3, how $\int_0^1x^{\lambda}\left(\phi(x)-\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{\phi^{(j)}(0)}{j!}x^j\right)dx$ becomes $\int_0^{\infty}x^{\lambda}\left(\phi(x)-\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{\phi^{(j)}(0)}{j!}x^j\right)dx$

Comment: It was a typo, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I now follow your argument. This is the first of the two expressions that I gave in my OP which I already understand. What is that the first expression reduces to the second when $-n - 1 < \mbox{Re}\lambda < -n$. You did say that the fact that the expressions are convergent helps show this. What I'd like to know is how. Thnaks.

Comment: How about this: in the strip, specifically when Re$\lambda < -n$ (or $-n > \mbox{Re}\lambda$) the summation term $\sum_{k = 0}^n$ disappears, while the integral $\int_0^1$ is valid when Re$\lambda > -n - 1$. This is how far I've gotten and I'm not even sure I'm on the right track.

Comment: Going back to your earlier remark, I don't know where you get $\int_1^{\infty} x^{\lambda + j}$ from.  I'm aware of $\int_0^{1} x^{\lambda + j}$ but not the latter.

Comment: The first step is the following: cut the integral in two parts: the first from $0$ to $1$ and the second from $1$ to $+\infty$. In the second integral I just used linearity of the integral.

Comment: Which integral are you referring to? The starting integral in your proof? Should we take this to the chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7289/mathematics

Comment: I've got it!!! I'm posting the answer.

Comment: Oops. Now I see. You've proved the expression back to front, whereas I went front to back.